# Filter operator on Single

Tags: rx-java, observable, reactivex

I start getting use to use Single instead of Observable in case that only 1 item it´s emitted, but then I realize that using Single there´s no filter operator.

Anybody knows an elegant way to do for instance

```
      Single.just("Single use test")
            .filter(s->s.contains("test"))--->How to use filter
            .map(s-> s.ToUpperCase())
```

Obviously I´m trying to avoid use map or doOnNext

Comment: Filtering a `Single` makes no sense because `Single` is supposed to emit exactly 1 `onSuccess` or `onError`. Why don't you use `Observable` which can become empty?

Comment: Yes we can, but the idea of use Single it was to improve readability, and know which pipes emit 1 or N

Comment: It is possible to add `Single.filter` but it has to return `Observable<T>`.

Comment: no point then, thanks

Comment: @akarnokd couldn't a Single.filter be an alias for `.toObservable.filter(XXX).toSingle()` ?

Comment: `.toObservable.filter(XXX).toSingle()` totally works. It will return an onError call with an exception (java.util.NoSuchElementException: The MaybeSource is empty) in case the item emitted was filtered